# Adding a new column in the list of orders PrestaShop 1.7.7.0

Tags: prestashop, new-operator

I want to add a new column in the order table grid in PrestaShop 1.7.7.0.

Currently, I've only managed to add a new column that gets its values based on the SQL query (code below).
However, I need to redo it so that it gets $ id_order from the current row of the table and processes it according to some function. Before it was done like this:

AdminOrdersController.php

```
$this->fields_list = array(
    'id_order' => array(
        'title' => $this->trans('ID', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
        'align' => 'text-center',
        'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
    ),
(...)
    'ms_pelne' => array(
        'title' => $this->trans('Pełne', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
        'align' => 'text-center',
        'callback' => 'msSprawdzZamowienie',
        'orderby' => false,
        'search' => false,
        'remove_onclick' => true,
    ),
));

public function msSprawdzZamowienie($id_order, $tr)
{
   (...)
}
```

Currently, unfortunately it does not work ...
My present code is:

```
<?php
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Column\Type\DataColumn;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Filter\Filter;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Column\Type\Common\BadgeColumn;
use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Grid\Column\ColumnCollection;

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class ms_MontowniaStron extends Module
{

    // const CLASS_NAME = 'ms_mstron2';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'ms_montowniastron';
        $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'ms';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = [
            'min' => '1.7',
            'max' => _PS_VERSION_
        ];
        $this->bootstrap = false;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('MS Pełne Zamówienie');
        $this->description = $this->l('Moduł pozwalający na wyświetlanie informacji o pełnym zamówieniu.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
    }




    /**
     * Install module and register hooks to allow grid modification.
     *
     * @see https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/use-hooks-on-modern-pages/
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install()
            //Installation des hooks
            || !$this->registerHook([
                'actionOrderGridDefinitionModifier',
                'actionOrderGridQueryBuilderModifier',
                'actionOrderGridDataModifier',
                'actionOrderGridPresenterModifier'
            ])
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }



    public function uninstall() {
        return parent::uninstall();
    }




    /**
     * Hooks allows to modify Customer grid definition.
     * This hook is a right place to add/remove columns or actions (bulk, grid).
     *
     * @param array $params
     */
    public function hookActionOrderGridDefinitionModifier(array $params)
    {


        /** @var GridDefinitionInterface $definition */
        $definition = $params['definition'];

        /** @var ColumnCollection */
        $columns = $definition->getColumns();

        // dodajemy nową
        $definition
        ->getColumns()
        ->addAfter(
            'id_order',
            (new BadgeColumn('ms_full_order'))
                ->setName($this->l('Pełne'))
                ->setOptions([
                    'field' => 'ms_full_order',
                    'badge_type' => 'success',
                    'empty_value' => '--',
                ])
        );

    }


    public function hookActionOrderGridQueryBuilderModifier(array $params)
    {
        
        $searchQueryBuilder = $params['search_query_builder'];

        $searchQueryBuilder->addSelect('(

            SELECT
              id_order
            FROM
              ms_orders AS msg
              LIMIT 1
                

        ) as ms_full_order');

    }



}
?>
```

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: Yes, below my code:

Comment: To whoever came from search like I just did: see https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/templating/admin-views/ and https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/override-decorate-controller/, "*Since PrestaShop 1.7, the back office is being progressively migrated to the Symfony framework. Even though modules are no longer allowed to override a complete controller like before (it was highly discouraged anyway), we have introduced new powerful and more efficient ways to customize the Back Office.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, below my code.

Upload to:
override/controllers/admin/AdminOrdersController.php

Key of code is function "msSprawdzZamowienie()".

```
    <?php

class AdminOrdersController extends AdminOrdersControllerCore
{

    public $toolbar_title;

    protected $statuses_array = array();


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        $this->table = 'order';
        $this->className = 'Order';
        $this->lang = false;
        $this->addRowAction('view');
        $this->explicitSelect = true;
        $this->allow_export = true;
        $this->deleted = false;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->_select = '
        a.id_currency,
        a.id_order AS id_pdf,
        a.id_order AS ms_pelne,
        CONCAT(LEFT(c.`firstname`, 1), \'. \', c.`lastname`) AS `customer`,
        osl.`name` AS `osname`,
        os.`color`,
        IF((SELECT so.id_order FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` so WHERE so.id_customer = a.id_customer AND so.id_order < a.id_order LIMIT 1) > 0, 0, 1) as new,
        country_lang.name as cname,
        IF(a.valid, 1, 0) badge_success';

        $this->_join = '
        LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'customer` c ON (c.`id_customer` = a.`id_customer`)
        INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'address` address ON address.id_address = a.id_address_delivery
        INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'country` country ON address.id_country = country.id_country
        INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'country_lang` country_lang ON (country.`id_country` = country_lang.`id_country` AND country_lang.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $this->context->language->id . ')
        LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_state` os ON (os.`id_order_state` = a.`current_state`)
        LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'order_state_lang` osl ON (os.`id_order_state` = osl.`id_order_state` AND osl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $this->context->language->id . ')';
        $this->_orderBy = 'id_order';
        $this->_orderWay = 'DESC';
        $this->_use_found_rows = true;

        $statuses = OrderState::getOrderStates((int) $this->context->language->id);
        foreach ($statuses as $status) {
            $this->statuses_array[$status['id_order_state']] = $status['name'];
        }

        $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_order' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('ID', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'class' => 'fixed-width-xs',
            ),
            'reference' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Reference', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            ),
            'ms_pelne' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Pełne', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'callback' => 'msSprawdzZamowienie',
                'orderby' => false,
                'search' => false,
                'remove_onclick' => false,
            ),
            'new' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('New client', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Feature'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'type' => 'bool',
                'tmpTableFilter' => true,
                'orderby' => false,
            ),
            'customer' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Customer', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'havingFilter' => true,
            ),
        );

        if (Configuration::get('PS_B2B_ENABLE')) {
            $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
                'company' => array(
                    'title' => $this->trans('Company', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                    'filter_key' => 'c!company',
                ),
            ));
        }

        $this->fields_list = array_merge($this->fields_list, array(
            'total_paid_tax_incl' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Total', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-right',
                'type' => 'price',
                'currency' => true,
                'callback' => 'setOrderCurrency',
                'badge_success' => true,
            ),
            'payment' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Payment', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
            ),
            'osname' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Status', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'color' => 'color',
                'list' => $this->statuses_array,
                'filter_key' => 'os!id_order_state',
                'filter_type' => 'int',
                'order_key' => 'osname',
            ),
            'date_add' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Date', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-right',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'filter_key' => 'a!date_add',
            ),
            'id_pdf' => array(
                'title' => $this->trans('PDF', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'align' => 'text-center',
                'callback' => 'printPDFIcons',
                'orderby' => false,
                'search' => false,
                'remove_onclick' => true,
            ),
        ));

        if (Country::isCurrentlyUsed('country', true)) {
            $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
            SELECT DISTINCT c.id_country, cl.`name`
            FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` o
            ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('orders', 'o') . '
            INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'address` a ON a.id_address = o.id_address_delivery
            INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'country` c ON a.id_country = c.id_country
            INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'country_lang` cl ON (c.`id_country` = cl.`id_country` AND cl.`id_lang` = ' . (int) $this->context->language->id . ')
            ORDER BY cl.name ASC');

            $country_array = array();
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $country_array[$row['id_country']] = $row['name'];
            }

            $part1 = array_slice($this->fields_list, 0, 3);
            $part2 = array_slice($this->fields_list, 3);
            $part1['cname'] = array(
                'title' => $this->trans('Delivery', array(), 'Admin.Global'),
                'type' => 'select',
                'list' => $country_array,
                'filter_key' => 'country!id_country',
                'filter_type' => 'int',
                'order_key' => 'cname',
            );
            $this->fields_list = array_merge($part1, $part2);
        }

        $this->shopLinkType = 'shop';
        $this->shopShareDatas = Shop::SHARE_ORDER;

        if (Tools::isSubmit('id_order')) {
            // Save context (in order to apply cart rule)
            $order = new Order((int) Tools::getValue('id_order'));
            $this->context->cart = new Cart($order->id_cart);
            $this->context->customer = new Customer($order->id_customer);
        }

        $this->bulk_actions = array(
            'updateOrderStatus' => array('text' => $this->trans('Change Order Status', array(), 'Admin.Orderscustomers.Feature'), 'icon' => 'icon-refresh'),
        );
    }


    public function msSprawdzZamowienie($id_order, $tr)
    {
        static $valid_order_state = array();

        $order = new Order($id_order);
        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($order)) {
            return '';
        }

        $products = $order->getProducts();

        $html = '';
        $products_available = array();

        foreach( $products AS $product )
        {
            $available = ( $product[ 'product_quantity' ] <= $product[ 'quantity' ] && $product[ 'quantity' ] > 0 ) ? '1' : '0';
            array_push( $products_available, $available );
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'order' => $order,
            'tr' => $tr,
        ));

        if( in_array( '0', $products_available ) ){
            $html = '<span style="background:red;color:#fff;padding:2px 5px;border-radius:3px;">NIE</span>';
        } else {
            $html = '<span style="background:green;color:#fff;padding:2px 5px;border-radius:3px;">TAK</span>';
        }

        return $html;
    }


}
```